# how join(long millis) works in the following example?

Tags: java, multithreading

```
class TestJoinMethod2 extends Thread{  
 public void run(){  
  for(int i=1;i<=5;i++){  
   try{  
    Thread.sleep(500);  
   }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}  
  System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());  
  }  
 }  
public static void main(String args[]){  
 TestJoinMethod2 t1=new TestJoinMethod2();  
 TestJoinMethod2 t2=new TestJoinMethod2();  
 TestJoinMethod2 t3=new TestJoinMethod2();  
 t1.start();  
 try{  
  t1.join(1500);  
 }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}  

 t2.start();  
 t3.start();  
 }
```

}
The output I get is something like below

```
Thread-0
Thread-0
Thread-0
Thread-1
Thread-2
Thread-0
Thread-1
Thread-2
Thread-0
Thread-1
Thread-2
Thread-1
Thread-2
Thread-1
Thread-2
```

The particular method join(long millis) describes that it Waits at most millis milliseconds for the thread to die.
Now my question is if Thread-0 dies after 1500 millis(i.e after first 3 times) then how does it get executed afterwards?

Comment: Could you format your code more nicely, please? It’s hard to follow the nesting, especially in `TestJoinMethod2`. Your IDE can do it for you (and for us).

Comment: `t.join()` _wait_ for `t` to die.  It doesn't _make_ `t` die.  `t.join()` doesn't do anything at all to thread `t`.

Answer (score 3):

The join(long) method waits for the thread to die for **at most** the given number of milliseconds. Since t1 isn't complete after 1500 ms the join call is simply making the main thread wait for 1500 ms.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join-long-